# Angular 8 - Dynamically insert Component into another component

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular8

I'm trying to create a dynamic card banner for my project. I want to be able to change the content of the cards dynamically so that I can display different content, depending on what the user wants to see.

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cards-eyedpeas-test) of the current situation. As you can see, the `CardService` creates the cards that should be displayed in the card banner.

My problem is, that I don't understand how I can access the content of the components i want to display in the cards.

---

After I created the StackBlitz, I tried a different approach and changed the content of `card-banner.component.ts`, `card-banner.component.html`and `card-content.component.html`:

### card-banner.component.ts

```js
import {Component, ComponentFactoryResolver, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {CardContentComponent} from '../card-content/card-content.component';
import {CardDirective} from '../../directives/card.directive';
import {CardItem} from '../card-item';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card-banner',
  templateUrl: './card-banner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card-banner.component.scss']
})
export class CardBannerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy  {

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  @Input() cards: CardItem[];

  @ViewChild(CardDirective, {static: true}) appCards: CardDirective;

  firstCard: CardItem;
  secondCard: CardItem;
  thirdCard: CardItem;

  CardList = [this.firstCard, this.secondCard, this.thirdCard];

  loadCards() {
this.cards.forEach((card, index) => {
      console.log(card.data)
      this.CardList[index] = card.data;
    });
  }

  addCard() {
    //TODO: sollte im Service passieren!
    this.cards.push(new CardItem(CardContentComponent, {name: 'Card Dynamisch'}));
    this.loadCards();
  }

  removeLastCard() {
    this.cards.pop();
    this.loadCards();
  }

  ngOnInit() {this.loadCards();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {}

}
```

### card-banner.component.html

```html
<button (click)="addCard()" class="btn">Add Card</button>
<button (click)="removeLastCard()" class="btn">Remove Card</button>

<div style="margin: auto;">
  <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="firstCard"></ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="secondCard"></ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="thirdCard"></ng-container>
</div>
```

### card-content.component.html

```html
<div >
  <ng-container>
    <button (click)="removeCard()" class="btn">Delete</button>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

---

The problem still remains: I don't know how I can 'render' the content of the cards dynamically.

Comment: In the StackBlitz you posted the card-content is loaded and the data is passed to the instance and rendered correctly. What type of access to the component is it you are missing?

Comment: In the StackBlitz, the first 'card' displays the following content `function TestCompComponent() { } `. This is not what I aim for. 
I want to have the whole html of the component to be rendered in this place.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think you should avoid creating components in your service. Just create a component the regular way, use your service to create an array of objects with the data needed for your cards, and then display it dynamically with ngFor in card-banner.component.ts:

```
<CardContentComponent *ngFor="let item of cards" [data]="item.data"></CardContentComponent>
```

Comment: The problem with this approach (which I had in mind at the start of my work on this element) is, that the data in this case would be different components. 
E.g. i want to have 3 cards where the content of the cards can be any other component of my project (or rather a selection of components that make sense). 
Therefore i need to display the complete component similar to `<app-example-component></app-example-component>`

Answer (score 0):

To the content you reached from appropriate sequense html-ts
To insert different data read about `<router-outlet>`